STM32 Multimaster / Multislave RS485 implementation with manual flow controll
I'm recently going crazy on a RS485 Multi Master implementation on STM32 and I can't figure out, what's my problem... After multiple days of figuring out, what's the issue, I turn to you and hope somebody here can spot the error.
I have the following setup:
I have a total of 6 STM32F030 microcontrollers, each with a RS485 transceiver.
3 of them are "Masters" and 3 of them are "Slaves"
That the masters don't conflict each other, they share a "I'm currently using the bus" line, with a pull-up, that each master can pull down to show the other masters, it's using the bus.

And it's somehow working well - until it doesn't...
So, the error is, that after a random amount of time (had anything from a couple of minutes to almost an hour), one of the master's seems to get stuck (maybe in a race condition?) and all communication stops.
The LED is turned on and remains on - so it's somewhat sure,
Here is the code I use (I have removed the Ringbuffer implementation as I use this code in many other projects and place and I'm sure no error is there). If you are missing some info, or the
#define MB_BUS_UART (&huart2)

typedef enum mb_bus_state_t {
    STATE_NEW_CMD,
    STATE_START_BLOCK,
    STATE_START,
    STATE_NEXT_TRY,
    STATE_START_RX,
    STATE_TX_CMD,
    STATE_WAIT_RX,
    STATE_ERROR
} mb_bus_state_t;

typedef struct mb_bus_buf_item_t {
    mb_bus_item_t item;
    mb_bus_cb_t   cbFkt;
} mb_bus_buf_item_t;

typedef struct mb_bus_rb_t {
    mb_bus_buf_item_t buffer[32];
    uint8_t           head;
    uint8_t           tail;
    uint8_t           count;
    mb_bus_buf_item_t current;
    mb_bus_state_t    state;
    uint8_t           retryCnt;
    uint8_t           errorCnt;
    ot_pulse_t        busTimeout;
    ot_pulse_t        busRetryWait;
    mb_bus_state_t    stateBefError;
} mb_bus_rb_t;

static mb_bus_rb_t Rb;
static uint8_t     RxBuf[10];
static uint8_t     TxBuf[10];

static bool              busTxCurrentItem(void);
static bool              busRbRemoveItem(void);
static mb_bus_buf_item_t busRbGetItem(void);
static HAL_StatusTypeDef busTxData(uint8_t*, uint8_t);
static HAL_StatusTypeDef busRxDataToIdle(void);
static void              busSetDir(bool);
static void              busDrvUnblock(void);
static void              busUartReset(void);

/**
 * @brief Initializes the Bus Driver.
 * 
 * This function initializes the Bus Driver by setting the necessary variables and configurations.
 * It resets the head, tail, and count of the ring buffer.
 * It unblocks the Bus Driver.
 * It sets the state of the bus to STATE_NEW_CMD.
 * It sets the RS845 driver direction to receive mode, but does not start to listen.
 */
void busDrvInit() {
    busUartReset();
    busDrvUnblock();
    Rb.state = STATE_NEW_CMD;

    //set to receive, but don't listen
    busSetDir(false);
}

/**
 * @brief Updates the bus driver state machine.
 * 
 * This function is responsible for updating the state machine of the bus driver.
 * It handles different states and performs necessary actions based on the current state.
 * 
 * @note This function assumes that the necessary variables and functions are defined and initialized properly.
 * 
 * @note This function should be called periodically to ensure proper functioning of the bus driver.
 */
void busDrvUpdate() {
    switch(Rb.state) {
        case STATE_NEW_CMD:
            if(!busRbIsEmpty()) {
                // reset error/retry counter
                Rb.retryCnt = 0;
                Rb.errorCnt = 0;
                // copy highest rb item as current item
                Rb.current = busRbGetItem();
                //immdiatly remove item from ring buffer as it is now WIP
                busRbRemoveItem();
                // start transmission
                Rb.state = STATE_START_BLOCK;
                busDrvUnblock();
            }
            break;

        case STATE_START_BLOCK:
            if((GPIOC->IDR & SP_BUS_MS_IN_Pin) != 0) {
                // no other master is using the bus
                // so block the other masters and start transmission
                GPIOC->BRR = SP_BUS_MS_OD_Pin;
                // init uart
                busUartReset();
                // turn on LED
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(P_LED_GPIO_Port, P_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                // set next state
                Rb.state = STATE_START;
            }
            break;

        case STATE_START:
            if(Rb.retryCnt < 3) {
                SetTimer(&Rb.busRetryWait, WAIT_START_TIME, false);
                Rb.state = STATE_NEXT_TRY;
                Rb.retryCnt++;
            } else {
                if(Rb.errorCnt < 3) {
                    // retry cnt back to 0 to give another 3 try
                    Rb.retryCnt = 0;
                    // inc the error counter
                    Rb.errorCnt++;
                    // reinit uart
                    busUartReset();
                    // set longer retry wait time
                    SetTimer(&Rb.busRetryWait, MBB_WAIT_AFTER_ERROR, false);
                    // set next state
                    Rb.state = STATE_NEXT_TRY;
                } else {
                    busDrvUnblock();
                    // go to next cmd - data loss
                    Rb.state = STATE_NEW_CMD;
                }
            }
            break;

        case STATE_NEXT_TRY:
            if(CheckTimer(&Rb.busRetryWait)) {
                Rb.state = STATE_TX_CMD;
                SetTimer(&Rb.busTimeout, MASTER_TIMEOUT, false);
                if(busTxCurrentItem())
                    break;

                Rb.busTimeout.isOn = false;
                Rb.state           = STATE_START;
            }
            break;

        case STATE_START_RX:
            Rb.state = STATE_WAIT_RX;
            if(HAL_OK != busRxDataToIdle())
                Rb.state = STATE_START_RX;
            if(CheckTimer(&Rb.busTimeout))
                Rb.state = STATE_START;
            break;

        case STATE_ERROR:
            if((Rb.stateBefError == STATE_NEW_CMD)
               || (Rb.stateBefError == STATE_START_BLOCK)) {
                busUartReset();
                busDrvUnblock();
                Rb.state = Rb.stateBefError;
            } else {
                busUartReset();
                Rb.state = STATE_START;
            }
            break;

        case STATE_TX_CMD:
        case STATE_WAIT_RX:
        default:
            if(!Rb.busTimeout.isOn)
                SetTimer(&Rb.busTimeout, MASTER_TIMEOUT, false);
            if(CheckTimer(&Rb.busTimeout)) {
                Rb.state = STATE_START;
            }
            break;
    }
}

void busErrorCb() {
    Rb.stateBefError = Rb.state;
    Rb.state         = STATE_ERROR;
}

/**
 * @brief Callback function for handling received messages on the bus.
 *
 * This function is called when a message is received on the bus. It extracts the message from the buffer,
 * checks if the message is valid, and handles the message accordingly.
 *
 * @param aSize The size of the received message.
 */
void busRxCplCB(uint16_t aSize) {
    mb_bus_item_t rxItem;
    data_conv_2_t crc;

    if(Rb.state != STATE_WAIT_RX) {
        // received without expecting
        return;
    }

    // check crc value
    crc.word = CrcCalc(RxBuf, aSize - 2);
    if((RxBuf[aSize - 1] != crc.byte[1]) || (RxBuf[aSize - 2] != crc.byte[0])) {
        return;
    }

    // extract msg from Buffer
    rxItem.head.byte = RxBuf[0];
    rxItem.cmd       = RxBuf[1];
    rxItem.data      = RxBuf[2];

    // check if answer to this msg
    if((CPB_RT_MB != rxItem.head.bits.recType)
       || (GetDeviceAddress() != rxItem.head.bits.add)
       || (1 != rxItem.head.bits.rw)) {
        // not correct answer - but we are in WAIT_RX state - so start over
        return;
    }

    // check if answer to this cmd
    if(Rb.current.item.cmd != rxItem.cmd) {
        // not correct answer - but we are in WAIT_RX state - so start over
        return;
    }

    //All ok, handle msg
    switch(Rb.current.item.cmd) {
        case MBBC_GET_STATUS:
            if(Rb.current.cbFkt != NULL) {
                Rb.current.cbFkt(rxItem.head.bits.position, rxItem.data);
            }
            // close cmd and kick Wd
            Rb.state = STATE_NEW_CMD;
            SpHandlerKickWd();
            busDrvUnblock();
            break;

        case MBBC_S0:
        case MBBC_S1:
        case MBBC_S2:
        case MBBC_S3:
            //just command - OK & NAV -> both valid answer
            if((RET_OK == rxItem.data) || (RET_NAV == rxItem.data)) {
                // close cmd and kick Wd
                Rb.state = STATE_NEW_CMD;
                SpHandlerKickWd();
                busDrvUnblock();
            } else {
                Rb.state = STATE_START;
            }
            break;

        default:
            // invalid cmd / answer - start over
            Rb.state = STATE_START;
    }
}

static void busUartReset() {
    // reset error and init uart
    MB_BUS_UART->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
    HAL_UART_DeInit(MB_BUS_UART);
    HAL_UART_Init(MB_BUS_UART);
}

/**
 * @brief Callback function called when the transmission is complete in the bus driver.
 * 
 * This function is called when the transmission of data is complete in the bus driver.
 * It updates the state of the driver based on the current state and performs necessary actions.
 * 
 * @note This function assumes that the variable `Rb` is accessible and represents the driver state.
 * 
 * @retval None
 */
void busTxCplCB() {
    switch(Rb.state) {
        case STATE_TX_CMD:
            Rb.state = STATE_WAIT_RX;
            if(HAL_OK != busRxDataToIdle())
                Rb.state = STATE_START_RX;
            break;

        default:
            //undefined state -> STATE_START
            Rb.state = STATE_START;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Receives data from the RS485 bus using interrupt-driven mode.
 * 
 * This function sets the RS485 driver direction to receive mode and initiates the reception of data from the RS485 bus using the UART peripheral in interrupt-driven mode.
 * 
 * @return The status of the UART reception operation.
 */
static HAL_StatusTypeDef busRxDataToIdle() {
    // set driver direction to receive
    busSetDir(false);

    // start receive interrupt and set error flag according the result
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
    status = HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_IT(MB_BUS_UART, RxBuf, MBB_BUF_LEN);
    return status;
}

/**
 * @brief Transmits the current item of the busDrv.
 *
 * This function copies the current item from the Rb structure to the TxBuf
 * and then sends the message using the busTxData function.
 *
 * @return True if the message was successfully sent, false otherwise.
 */
static bool busTxCurrentItem() {
    // put the data from Ringbuffer to TxBuf
    // Code section removed as sure no error here

    //send message
    return (busTxData(TxBuf, 3) == HAL_OK);
}

/**
 * @brief Unblock the bus driver.
 *
 * This function unblocks the bus driver by performing the following steps:
 * 1. Sets the P_LED pin to GPIO_PIN_SET.
 * 2. Sets the RS-845 driver direction to false.
 * 3. Sets the SP_BUS_MS_OD pin to GPIO_PIN_SET.
 * 4. Deinitializes the MB_BUS_UART.
 */
static void busDrvUnblock() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(P_LED_GPIO_Port, P_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    busSetDir(false);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SP_BUS_MS_OD_GPIO_Port, SP_BUS_MS_OD_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_UART_DeInit(MB_BUS_UART);
}

/**
 * @brief Send data over RS485
 *
 * @param[in] aData Data to send
 * @param[in] aLen Length of the data to send
 */
static HAL_StatusTypeDef busTxData(uint8_t* aData, uint8_t aLen) {
    data_conv_2_t crc;
    crc.word        = CrcCalc(aData, aLen);
    aData[aLen]     = crc.byte[0];
    aData[aLen + 1] = crc.byte[1];
    aLen += 2;
    busSetDir(true);
    return HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(MB_BUS_UART, aData, aLen);
}

/**
 * @brief Set the RS485 driver direction
 *
 * @param aDir Direction of the RS485 driver, true for output, false for input
 */
static void busSetDir(bool aDir) {
    if(aDir) {
        //send
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(U2_DE_GPIO_Port, U2_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    } else {
        // receive
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(U2_DE_GPIO_Port, U2_DE_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}

The UART is initialized as follows:
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 19200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_DMADISABLEONERROR_INIT;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.DMADisableonRxError = UART_ADVFEATURE_DMA_DISABLEONRXERROR;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


I'm not going to read all of that code to figure out the details. I just want to point out that even with the shared "bus busy" line, there's still a small chance that two masters will grab it at the same time and collide. Do you handle that?

@DaveTweed currently not, how would you catch that situation?

Not knowing the details of your protocol, all I can say is that generically, you need some way to detect collisions on the RS-485 bus. It could be as simple as a timeout when you don't get a response. I'll take a closer look sometime tomorrow.

The protocol is fairly similar to a MODBUS, just customized to reduce some bytes.
Each message consist of x byte (number unknown at reception. It has a 1 byte head with an adress, 1 byte command followed by x byte of data, followed by 2 byte CRC/MODBUS.

"Seems to get stuck" and you have done what to determine where and why? SWD is a powerful tool to know what happens, where, and why.

Can you assign 3 different delay values to the masters before they try to claim the bus after the last transmission?

@Justme the problem I have with SWD is following: I have reduced the problem / question - in my system I have 20x the 3 Master / 3 Slave configuration. And till now I didn't on the master connected to SWD (and it might take time to happen). Or is there a way to connect it after the fact, that I don't know of?
What I have done to determine the status is to switch on a status LED, when a master takes the bus and turn-off when a master releases the bus. On the Slave side, I have done the same - when a message is received, the status LED flashes.

So from that I can see: at some point 1 master takes the bus and does not release it anymore - the 3 slave do not receive further messages.

Modbus protocol is a single master protocol, it needs a bridge product to bridge two networks (or have a MCU to have two Modbus ports, i.e. basically two networks) if there are more than one master.

In support of not using the shared master idea - https://wiki.c2.com/?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork

There was a smart guy, around 1986 he invented the P-Net with multi-masters by just looking on the activity on the bus (RS485) he was able by time slot to give different masters time to send. There was even an IEC norm 61158 made.

@Erik IEC 61158 is the general IEC standard series specifying all things fieldbus, not only P-Net, although it might very well be included in that standard (I don't have it in front of me to verify).

IEC 61158 Type 4, https://www.p-net.org/

I spent a bunch of time trying to understand your bus state machine in the function busDrvUpdate() and controlled by the variable Rb.state. It's very complicated, with some state transitions initiated by callback functions outside of busDrvUpdate().
That's a red flag right there — if multiple functions in multiple threads (I'm assuming these callbacks occur inside interrupt service routines) can update the same variable Rb.state, there needs to be some sort of access control in order to avoid collisions.
For example, suppose busDrvUpdate() is executing when one of these callbacks occurs, and it is about to update Rb.state. Even if the callback writes to Rb.state, that value will be immediately overwritten when busDrvUpdate() resumes. Not good — you need something like a semaphore to control updates to this variable.

This might be the point. You are right, the ...Cb functions are called from the UART interrupt. From your experience, what is the better way, adding some atomic safeguard to the Rb.state access?  Or what would be the recommended way to change Rb.State after the Rx and Tx interrups are completed?

The most straightforward way would be to have each callback set a separate flag, and check/clear those flags inside busDrvUpdate(). That makes Rb.state completely private to that function.

Sorry, it took me some time to verify it. You were absolutely right, and this solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Make your live easy! I would drop the idea of using the physical line for communicating the 'bus-busy-state'.
Assuming your setup is static, i would assing one of the masters as 'root-master' via e.g. the SW-configuration. This MCU initializes a token which is passed by some well defined scheme to all the other masters on the bus. This scheme can be either time-, traffic-, or bandwith-focused.
Of course this approach comes with some problems (increased traffic, different SW-configurations, extra layer in your protocol) but in general it is reliable and simple.
